# Clip Text composable

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I'm trying to replicate the Eclipse Google Home Screensaver in Jetpack Compose.
However I'm completely stuck at how I can achieve the clipping effect as seen on the example.

[image: Eclipse - Dark one of Google Home's Screensaver]

Currently I tried following using a `Row` and some weighted `Text` composables.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Eclipse() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .background(Color.Black)
    ) {
        EclipseIntTile(0, modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))
        EclipseIntTile(4, modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))
        EclipseIntTile(5, modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))
        EclipseIntTile(2, modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))
    }
}
@Composable
fun EclipseIntTile(i: Int, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text("$i", modifier = modifier, style = TextStyle(fontSize = 140.sp, color = Color.White))
}
```

Which yields following

[image]

How can I configure the `Row` to stop *wrapping* the `Text`'s?
Is it possible to do this without hard coding a size on the `Row`?

Answer (score 0):

A decent solution would be to use a `BoxWithConstraints` which exposes a `size` value. Now, you can place your snippet inside this Box, then use the size value to set the widths of the `Text`s, dividing the space equally among the children. Then, you can use the same `size` value to set the font size as well. Now you see this is not really hard-coding since the sizes will adjust to various screen dimensions. So, this could be one workaround.

On a different version, you could use a `Layout` Composable, which exposes `constraints`. Layout is the official Compose way of building custom widgets like this, so... Best of luck